# Pandas to_csv method doesn't allow tabspace separator

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am transforming dataframe into csv file with tabspace separator. But the resultant csv file doesn't include tabspace.

If I omit the separtaor, then by default it takes comma separator and the text of the second column placed under double quote.

Here is the example.

```
 col1  col2
0 123v345 filename is alphanumeric
1 123456  filename is numeric
```

This is my df. 
Now when I use

```
with open(os.path.join(dataDir,"csvFileName" + ".csv") as csvFile:  
    df.to_csv(csvfile, index=False)
```

then I get below

```
col1,col2
123v345,"filename is alphanumeric"
123456,"filename is numeric"
```

Now when I use df.to_csv(csvfile, sep="\t",index=False)
then I get below without space.

```
col1,col2
123v345filename is alphanumeric
123456filename is numeric
```

Comment: I run your code properly on `pandas=0.23.4`

Comment: What is your pandas version as this works fine on pandas `0.24.0`

Comment: Pandas version 0.23.4 and it always gives me without tab sapce.

Comment: Maybe try `df.to_csv(csvfile, sep="\t",index=False)` without using `with open ...`

Comment: doesn't work even without open.

Comment: What are you opening the output file with?

Comment: @asongtoruin: I didn't understand what you said.